# Problem compiling with TeXLive

Tags: texlive, compiling, ubuntu

I am a Ubuntu user, and recently I had a problem with my upgrade from an older version of Ubuntu to a newer one, so I had to wipe everything out and start back from scratch. Unfortunately, that involves setting LaTeX to work back again.

The problem I have is the following : I don't remember what I was using as a LaTeX distribution before, but I know that now I am using TeXLive ; when I run pdflatex, it gives me an error line on every single line in my code, which usually looks like this for one of my average-looking files :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt]{article}
\usepackage[isolatin]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}

%Specific to TikZ

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
....
```

For instance, I get told from the second line that "File isolatin.def not found" and then my packages ending in ".sty" keep appearing a lot in the errors. If I keep letting them go though (by pressing enter in my terminal, it kind of ignores the warning) I can compile and get my .pdf file, but it won't show with all my pretty packages. Any idea about why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed the package `texlive-full`?

Comment: Looks like I hadn't... didn't even know about this package! It's installing right now. I'll fill you in with how everything goes afterwards. Thanks to @Higgs for the edit ; that's actually what I wanted to output in my question, but I didn't know how.

Comment: @HåkonMalmedal : Thanks! Everything works just fine now. Feel free to type this as an answer and I'll accept it for the upvotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `texlive-full` is a “metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live”.

Comment: ... and this brings several gigabytes of obscure cruft onto your machine. Barely recommended.

Answer (score 9):

There's never been an `isolatin` option for `inputenc`: you probably want `latin1`.

The package `aeguill` is *very* obsolete. To get correct guillemets just load `fontenc` with the `T1` option. You may want also to load the Latin Modern fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10 pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}

%Specific to TikZ

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
```

Comment: I never actually bothered about those packages ; I copy-pasted the list from one of my friends and then just let it there. Thanks for noticing this for me

Answer (score 1):

I use the original TeXLive DVD and install it in /opt/texlive/. After installation
I set the the path variable to point to the new TeXLive folder. And it works for me. Since I use this method I has no more problem with TeXLive, and I don't use TeXLive distrituted by Ubuntu repos any more.

You can download the DVD here: http: // ctan . org / mirrors (choose one of them), then follow the instruction here: (sorry, I'm a new user so I can post only 2 links pls remove the blank.)
(mounting ISO file etc....)
http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

(Install TeXLive)
http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html